# Submiting the google form via VBA prefill

Tags: vba, google-forms

I am trying to prefil and submit a google form. But I am not sure how I will click the submit button on the google form  from my code.

Please assist with this.

Using VBA to pass data via a google form to google speardsheet.

I am able to manually click  submit button on IE  and data gets saved.

But what / how to do this via code!!!

```
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/12344545/viewform"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
Loop

Set Doc = IE.document

Doc.getElementById("entry.2116136539").Value = sht.Range("A" & i).Value
Doc.getElementById("entry.451687686").Value = sht.Range("B" & i).Value


Doc.getElementById("?????????").Click


Next i
```

Just need the syntax for submit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Loop will do that:**

Set a ObjCollection to the Elements by Tag name `span`, Then loop through them and get the element whose innertext is `Submit`. Assign it to a new variable & Click that Element out of the Loop.

```
Set objCollection = Nothing

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")

i = 0


    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).innerText = "Submit" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

objElement.Click
```

[Link to my Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIjYMZ0Gn1I)

Comment: Thanks Mikku. I had found out that you could do a form submit and that will do the job.